# Reasons for Conspiracy Theories

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, off-topic

A lot of the questions on Skeptics revolve around the legitimacy of conspiracy theories or other theories. Is it considered off-topic to ask for the origins of these theories as separate questions? If not, can they be asked for as parts of other questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be on topic if there was a notable origin-story for a conspiracy. Then, you could ask if that origin story was correct.

Sometimes, if the origin is relevant to the analysis of the conspiracy, it can come out in an answer, but that is usually the preference of the answer author, and not dictated by the question.

Alternatively, visit [skeptics chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/311/hub-of-reason), and people will gladly discuss this topic with you.